# Send JSONObject using HttpConnection POST with BlackBerry

Tags: json, post, blackberry, httpconnection

I'm trying to do a blackbery application that can send a `JSONObject` through a `HttpConnection` POST request. The JSONObject is

```
{ 
   "Contrasena" : "hy1tSPQc3K4IlSZLvd7U7g==", 
   "Plataforma" : "A", 
   "Usuario" : "user2323" 
}
```

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [URLEncodedPostData](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/blackberry/api/browser/URLEncodedPostData.html) class for this. Use like

```
  httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

  httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

  URLEncodedPostData encPostData = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8", false);

  encPostData.setData(JsonString);//set your jsonstring

  byte[] postData = encPostData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");   

  httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postData.length)); 

  httpConn.openOutputStream().write(encPostData.getBytes()); 

  int Response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
```